# Manually Edit cells in pandas data frame on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

We have the following dummy data frame that collects counts of warnings (based on a reason) for a given date:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['2022-10-13','one',123],['2022-10-13','two',77123],
                              ['2022-10-13','three',451], ['2022-10-13','three',77]]),
                            columns = ['date','reason','count'])
```

The problem is in the count column

```
     date             reason     count
0    2022-10-13       one        123
1    2022-10-13       two        77123
2    2022-10-13       three      451
3    2022-10-13       three      77
```

The data for reasons **one** and **three** needs to be scaled by 100 as it is stored in a minimized way on the database.

Is there a way to traverse the cells and add '00' to the counts or multiply by 100 where reason is not equal to two? And end up with something like this:

```
     date             reason     count
0    2022-10-13       one        12300
1    2022-10-13       two        77123
2    2022-10-13       three      45100
3    2022-10-13       three      7700
```

How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure the column `count` are integers (or floats), then use [.loc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and select the rows you wish to adapt (`temp.reason != 'two'`) and make the change (`temp['count'] * 100`):

```
temp['count'] = temp['count'].astype(int)
temp.loc[temp.reason != 'two', 'count'] = temp['count'] * 100
print(temp)
```

Output

```
         date reason  count
0  2022-10-13    one  12300
1  2022-10-13    two  77123
2  2022-10-13  three  45100
3  2022-10-13  three   7700
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `*=100` for multiple values if not matched by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
temp['count'] = temp['count'].astype(int)

temp.loc[temp['reason'].ne('two'), 'count'] *= 100
print (temp)

         date reason  count
0  2022-10-13    one  12300
1  2022-10-13    two  77123
2  2022-10-13  three  45100
3  2022-10-13  three   7700
```

Comment: @TCMolenaar is there any advantage of using "ne" instead of "!="?

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus - It is difference if chain conditions - `temp['reason'].ne('two') | temp['reason'].ne('one')` vs - `(temp['reason'] != 'two') | (temp['reason'] != 'one')`

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus this case no. There are some cases where `.ne` is desired, when comparing two dataframes for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`

```
temp['count'] = temp['count'].astype(int)
temp['count'] = np.where(temp['reason']!='two', temp['count']*100, temp['count'])
```